# How to bind checkboxes with Angular in reactive forms

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

Actually, I made a dummy project on health care so in that I made a component having Test Services in that I made a Radio Button, on the click of the radio Specific data goes to dropdown which is Services, and on the click on specific service I need sub-services in checkboxes and then on the click of submit I need that goes to JSON server.

I tried I made every thing radio dependent dropdown n checkboxes too but, when I check with the debugger it fetches the target value in the check box only true no value, so I need value in the checkboxes.

In this image, I bind the data from .ts to HTML and apply the for loop [In this ts file I call the change event with the event.target.value here in change service I get the value but when I see with debugger its an empty string only.

The test service with the subservice data:
[the HTML file here I made custom checkboxes and bind them with subServiices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktkZH.jpg)

Code:

```
<!-- For SubServices checkboxes -->
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
  <i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
  <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <!-- <label for="testService" class="form-label">Sub Services</label><br> -->
      <!-- (change)="onCheckboxChange ($event)" -->
      <div class="check" *ngFor="let sub of subServiceList"> --> <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
          formControlName="subService" | id="flexCheckChecked" [value]="sub.subService_id"
          (change)="onCheckChange($event)"> <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
          {{sub.subService_name}}
          <!-- [checked]="{{sub.select}}" -->
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[The ts file here I create the change event with the help of that I get my target id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDb96.jpg)

Code:

```
  //to change the service calling change event and shows the dependent subservice in dropdown
  changeService(event: any) {
    debugger;
    let serviceId = event.target.value;
    this.subServiceList = this.testService.
      getSubService().
      filter((u) => u.service_id == serviceId);
    console.log(this.subServicelist);
  }

  onCheckChange(event: any) {
    const checkid = event.target.value;
    console.log(checkid);
    this.subServiceList = this.subServicelist.filter(
      (e) => e.subService_id == checkid
    );
  }
```

[The test service here I made the JSON data so that I can fetch that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAlxb.jpg)

Code:

```
getSubService(): ISubService[] { 
  return [
    { 
      subService_id: 1501, 
      service_id: 115, 
      select: false, 
      subService_name: 'X-RAY both Kneen', 
    }, 
    { 
      subService_id: 1502, 
      service_id: 115, 
      select: false, 
      subService_name: 'X-RAY chest', 
    }, 
    {
      subService_id: 1503, 
      service_id: 115, 
      select: false, 
      subService_name: 'X-RAY spine',
    },
  ]
}
```

[The issue which I facing that I don't get the value of subservice in the request of post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmCsM.jpg)

Comment: please share code instead of screenshots, also please share the value of `subServiceList`

Comment: as i mention above the subServiceList is my selected data which i get from dropdown . whichever service i ll select it wil show me that if i select x-ray it will show

Comment: {
        subService_id: 1501,
        service_id: 115,
        select: false,
        subService_name: 'X-RAY both Kneen',
      },
      {
        subService_id: 1502,
        service_id: 115,
        select: false,
        subService_name: 'X-RAY chest',
      },
      {
        subService_id: 1503,
        service_id: 115,
        select: false,
        subService_name: 'X-RAY spine',
      },
      {
        subService_id: 1504,
        service_id: 115,
        select: false,
        subService_name: 'X-RAY neck',
      }, it will show this

Comment: I think attaching a stackblitz of the relevant code will be helpful. You can create a demo Angular project here: https://stackblitz.com/ . You can also update your question with the code.